# 'Cannot allocate memory' error - insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

Tags: java, hadoop

I have been trying to process 1000 images using hipi - 134MB, trying the Calculate averages tutorial as given in website [Getting Started](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/gettingstarted.html). The program runs well for 500 images and 100 images. For 1000 images, HIB creation was fast, but I cannot run the mapreduce. It says There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. I have 64 GB space in my hard disk available for use, and I have already updated my mapred-site.xml as -

```
<property>
 <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
 <value>-Xmx8192m</value>
</property>
```

Still, I am not able to get it to run.

```
15/06/20 07:41:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local2138318905_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/06/20 07:41:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/06/20 07:41:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/06/20 07:41:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 9% reduce 0%
15/06/20 07:41:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/06/20 07:41:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 15% reduce 0%
15/06/20 07:41:53 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/06/20 07:41:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000ef867000, 102338560, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)**

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 102338560 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/ubuntu/hipi-release/hs_err_pid10440.log
```

Comment: So what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: I consider your point, but the images total to only 134 MB, very small size as compared to the size hipi is designed to process(TBs of data). I am not getting how is even 1 GB of ram not enough for it?

Comment: Are you familiar with Processing with Hadoop? Because this doesn't look like it. Processing large number of images on a single node cluster almost never has caused any problems, nor are any such things documented by hipi or any other users.
If you haven't done this before, then kindly don't engage further, let any other user with hadoop/hipi experience answer this.

Thanks.